# Как сделать смену имени пользователя django?

Tags: python, django

Хочу реализовать на сайте смену ника пользователя в стандартной модели `User` через форму. Я попытался сделать это сам, но не вышло, в ник записывается просто какая-то ссылка. Как это реализовать правильно?

Вот моя попытка реализации:

Форма

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    new_name = forms.CharField(label='Ваше имя', max_length=255)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username',)

    def clean_username(self, new_name=new_name):
        new_name = self.cleaned_data.get(new_name)
        name = self.cleaned_data['username']
        User.objects.filter(username=name).update(username=new_name)
```

Класс представления:

```
class ChangeName(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
    form_class = UserForm
    template_name = 'infoprjct/change_name.html'
    success_url = 'home'
```

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смог решить свою проблему. Возможно кому либо будет полезно.

В форме нужно поставить проверку аккаунта через эмеил, или через любое другое поле.
Примерно так это выглядит:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(label='Новое имя', max_length=255)
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Ваша почта', max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'username')

    def clean_username(self):
        name = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        User.objects.filter(email=email).update(username=name)
```

В классе представления все оставляем так же.
Лучше решения пока что не нашел, и да оно требует некоторых допилов(под индивидуальности проекта), но все же оно работает. Если есть варианты лучше - обязательно пишите.